# Flutter : InteractiveViewer inside Stack

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-positioned

**Problem :**

- I am trying to scale widgets inside a `Stack` but that does not seem to work.
- The solution was to add `constrained: false` to the `InteractiveViewer`.
- But then, it throws error saying "**widgets have infinite size**", which is true thanks to `constrained: false`. Because it removes all constrains from `InteractiveViewer`
- I also tried wrapping `Stack` and each `canvasElement` with `Container` or `SizedBox.shrink` but both don't seem to work.

**Goal :**

- The goal is to be able to **Pan** and **Scale** widgets inside a `Stack`

**Here is my code :**

- **Note :** I have removed `GestureDetector` or else code would be too long to read

```
class _EditorState extends State<Editor> {
  List<Widget> _canvasElements = [];
  List<Offset> _canvasElementOffsets = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _canvasElements.add(Text('Scale me'));
    _canvasElementOffsets.add(Offset(150, 250));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: List.generate(
          _canvasElements.length,
          (index) => Positioned(
            left: _canvasElementOffsets[index].dx,
            top: _canvasElementOffsets[index].dy,
            child: InteractiveViewer(
              minScale: 0.5,
              maxScale: 5,
              constrained: false,
              child: _canvasElements[index],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Widgets are moving but not scaling :**

[image: Flutter Editor]